# Need help using <c:forEach> in JSP/JSTL

Tags: arrays, foreach, jstl, html-table, javabeans

I am trying to  iterate through a 2d array of integers and represent them in a grid using the `<table>` tag.  The catch is that I am not allowed to use any java-script.  I know it is something to the effect of the below code, but more complicated.  And `boardArray` returns a 2d integer array.  So how would I extract the value at each cell?  There is a predetermined size of the array as well.

```
       <c:forEach var="array" items="${bean.boardArray}">
            <tr> 
                <td>${print out contents of a row}</td>
            </tr> 
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that with plain HTML. You've mentioned HTML in the original question title, but since you've attached the `javabeans` tag and mentioned the `c:forEach` tag, I suppose you mean JSP and JSTL instead of HTML.
Here the JSP+JSTL solution, formatted to be better readable. The bean code:

```
package com;

public class TransferBean {
    private int[][] _boardArray = {
        { 1, 2, 33, 0, 7},
        { 13, 11, 7, 5, 3},
        { 5, 3, 2, 1, 1},
    };


    public int[][] getBoardArray() {
        return _boardArray;
    }

    public int getBoardArrayRowLength() {
        if (_boardArray == null || _boardArray.length == 0
                || _boardArray[0] == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return _boardArray[0].length;
    }
}
```

Here the JSP file content:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.TransferBean" />

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${bean.boardArrayRowLength}">
            <th>Column ${i}</th>
        </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${bean.boardArray}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                <td>
                    ${column}
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The array content is rendered by two nested `c:forEach` loops. The outer loop iterates over the rows, and for each row, the nested loop iterates over the columns in the given row.

Above example looks like this in a browser:
[image: JSTL iteration over 2D array]